# How to subscribe to native Ethereum transfer from Argent wallets?

Tags: events, smart-contract-wallets

I am wondering how do I subscribe to native ETH transfer events such as this one https://etherscan.io/tx/0x7357f1f0885811b2888dad7e7b1aa0f3016c7b0f8a179e37e463d5e941889bab#eventlog with `topic[0]: 0x7d2476ab50663f025cff0be85655bcf355f62768615c0c478f3cd5293f807365`.

If my understanding is correct, from the docs linked below, this is a native ETH transfer from the Argent Relayer EOA to the BaseWallet contract invoked by some Module contracts.

https://github.com/argentlabs/argent-contracts/blob/develop/specifications/specifications.pdf
https://docs.argent.xyz/wallet-connect-and-argent#meta-transactions-and-relayers

My question is where is the specific event/function for this? I tried looking through the smart contract code https://github.com/argentlabs/argent-contracts, attempting to find the event signature that I can use the ABI to extract the event from the log but I could not find the appropriate event. Is this an anonymous event without an explicit event signature? How should I securely identified the transfer from the log?

My current approach is to match the event logs with `topic[0]: 0x7d2476ab50663f025cff0be85655bcf355f62768615c0c478f3cd5293f807365` then get the sender, recipient and value from topics[1,2,3] accordingly. Is this the way to do it and is this secure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for known event signatures in the [Ethereum Signature Database](https://www.4byte.directory).

It corresponds to `Invoked(address,address,uint256,bytes)`.

Using Etherscan [vmtrace](https://etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0x27227da891d3bdc12144362c21ce7a5b100156784062ec6227dab428a3d529d1&type=parity) it reveals it is calling `invoke` functiun from [BaseWallet](https://etherscan.io/address/0xb6d64221451edbac7736d4c3da7fc827457dec03#code). It performs the transfer with `.call()` and emits the invoke event.

```
function invoke(address _target, uint _value, bytes calldata _data) external moduleOnly returns (bytes memory _result) {
    bool success;
    // solium-disable-next-line security/no-call-value
    (success, _result) = _target.call.value(_value)(_data);
    if (!success) {
        // solium-disable-next-line security/no-inline-assembly
        assembly {
            returndatacopy(0, 0, returndatasize)
            revert(0, returndatasize)
        }
    }
    emit Invoked(msg.sender, _target, _value, _data);
}
```

Comment: I did suspect it was the `Invoked` event, however there's no event name for the log shown on etherscan. I have also just tried the signature database you linked here, but the search did not return anything.

Comment: @tbraden It has function signatures and event signatures, if you select event signatures it will find the Invoked event (I found the event there). Etherscan just show the more common events, you can try reaching them to include the Invoked event.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, I will try out the `Invoked` event. Just another question if I may: instead of unpacking the event with the contract ABI, is it safe/sufficient to match only the event signature/topics[0] if I want to capture details from this specific event?